# Defining variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explain the difference between using a $ when defining variables in jQuery and not. Does it have any impact on performance?

```
var $someVar = $("a");
var someVar = $("a");
```

Also, what is the difference in calling variables with and without $(someVar) For example:

```
$(someVar).html();
someVar.html();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first snippet, there is **no** difference between those two. It's just a "`notification`" that this variable is holding a `wrappet set` of jQuery objects, which is commonly used by some developers.

In your second snippet you are actually doing two different things. You are wrapping `someVar` into a jQuery object and then access a `jQuery method` (html()).
In this example `someVar` could contain a `DOM element` or a `selector string` like "#some_element_id".

The other line assumes that `someVar` already IS a jQuery object, otherwise this call would fail.

Answer (score 2):

There is no performance difference, it's just an identifier. `$foo` is often used to refer to jquery objects by experienced authors so as to not confuse them with non-jquery objects in complex scripts.

As for the `$()` wrapping, you can reference a DOMElement and wrap it in jQuery, eg

```
var e = document.body; $(e).hide()
```

If we tried `e.hide()` there would be no defined method as the body element doesn't have that method, it's only provided by the jQuery prototype chain.

Answer (score 2):

`$somevar` and `somevar` are both the same . It is a convention to use a $ before a jquery variale so that you know that it is a jquery wrapped object .
( btw, $ were introduced in javascript to distinguish machine generated code for human written code ) 
However , $(somevar) and somevar are completely different . 
$(somevar) -> You are calling the Jquery function and passing it somevar . You can also read this as Jquery(somevar) . So if somevar is referring to a dom id , the dom object would be wrapped by jquery and returned .

Comment: +1 for ( btw, $ were introduced in javascript to distinguish machine generated code for human written code )